# Directing example.com to www.example.com

Tags: dns, cross-domain, digital-ocean, cname

I have a Django website in DigitalOcean, everything works fine expect routing **example.com** to **www.example.com**

I normally fix this using `CNAME` as the following, and all answers I have found also provide this, but it doesn't work in my case:

```
Hostname   Alias Of    TTL(Seconds)
www          @         43200
```

This normally works in GoDaddy, but in DigitalOcean the `www.example.com` takes me to the welcome to Nginx page.

So how can I get the `www.@.com` to display the website?

Comment: If the request reaches your webserver, it means it is not a DNS problem, but a webserver configuration problem, as you seem to have discovered.

Comment: hi does adding .example.com make the site vulnerable to HTTP Response splitting or any other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To future enquirers, I found a solution.

When using `gunicorn` and `nginx` as I have done in DigitalOcean

In `/etc/nginx/sites-available/site-name`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name .example.com;
```

in `server_name` add `.example.com`, with emphasies to the **.** before `example.com`
and make your `CNAME` record as I had described in the question.